# Angular 5 Compare date in component

Tags: angular, date, components, angular5

I need help to compare the date.
for example

```
today:Date=new Date();
endDate='9/17/18, 9:00 PM';
if(this.today>this.endDate){
....
}
```

I need to set date and compare it.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
XXX

Answer (score 2):

What you are going to want to do is

```
today: Date = new Date();
endDate = new Date(2018,8,17);

if(this.today > this.endDate){
   // Do Something
}
```

So basically you need to convert your date string into a date object, then you can compare your two dates like you would any other value..

the syntax for creating a date object is as follows

```
new Date(year, month, day, [hour, minute, second, millisecond])
```

you can see a stackblitz of the working code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpbkqu

Comment: I am get this error message:     Module parse failed: Invalid number (24:43)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: Your code has misstake new Date(2018,09,17) is not the same 9/17/18, cause monthes are counted from 0. So correct would be new Date(2018,08,17)

Comment: export class AppComponent {  today=new Date();
  endDate=new Date(2018,09,17,22,0,0,0);if(this.today >this.endDate ){...}}

Comment: @Sara Ive updated the answer, you have put the date in wrong

Comment: Sorry not working.export class AppComponent implements OnInit { today:Date=new Date();
  endDate:Date=new Date(2018,09,17,22,0,0,0); ngOnInit() {if(this.today >this.endDate){
      ...
    }
  }} throws error Module parse failed: Invalid number 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. I also reference of https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_new_all

Comment: Eventhough i send like this endDate:Date=new Date(2018,09,17); It throws error

Comment: I think you are working in js and i am working in angular.Passing date inside date function is throwing error.

Comment: I have created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpbkqu which is working with no errors please copy what I have done there

Comment: @Sara - When creating the date, use `8` or `9` for the month, not `09` (remove the leading zero).

Answer (score -1):

you can use moment.js, it's easy

```js
const now = moment(new Date());
const target = moment('9/17/18, 9:00');
const isOver = now.diff(target, 'seconds') < 0;
console.log('isOver' , isOver);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working.`export class AppComponent implements OnInit { today:Date=new Date(); endDate:Date=new Date('September 17, 2018 22:00:00'); ngOnInit() {if(this.today >this.endDate){  console.log("closed"); } }}` Thank you all for your comment and time

Comment: I though this might help someone.but what is wrong with this answer and why i am getting negative vote.Please help me to understand.